# badges from sister sites rendered with badge graphic from currently visited site

Tags: bug, status-declined, badges, sister-site

So, I was on Sci-Fi.se and noticed I got a badge from MV.SE, but for some hilarious reason, it rendered as the logo for the rebel alliance. I checked other sites, and sure enough badges in your history render the badge image for whichever site they are on. I'm not sure if this could be considered a bug, but I'll raise it anyway so it's documented.[image]

Comment: We would need to re-engineer quite a lot in order to get to what you are looking for. For very little gain - not going to happen any time soon.