# Icons of badges in the "accounts" section of the user page

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page

If I am on a SE site and I navigate to my own user page by clicking the link at the upper right corner, the page has a section under the title "Accounts", where I can find my accounts on other SE sites, followed by the numbers of each type of badge I have obtained on that site. This is good, but IMHO it is not perfect.

Currently, the icons used in this area for the badges are solely dependent on the SE site that I am currently in. Wouldn't it be better if we display the icons for the corresponding SE site instead?

To clarify what I mean I will use a simple example. If I am at puzzling SE and navigate to my user page, the badges there will all show as pieces of jigsaw puzzle. However, I expect the icon for the badge after the link to chemistry SE to be a half filled flask instead.

This is a feature request and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is also what happens when you earn badges in the achievement dropdown. That [bug isn't going to be fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286253/323179), and neither will this one most likely.

Comment: @Laurel I see, thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, SE loads one set of badge icons, which are the ones for the current site, and uses them for any badge-related displays -- badges on the current site, badges on other sites shown in the "Accounts" section, and badge awards shown in the achievements drop-down.  It would [require significant re-engineering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286253/badges-from-sister-sites-rendered-with-badge-graphic-from-currently-visited-site#comment928670_286253) to change this, and also extra page-loading time, for a *very* minor benefit.

Having the current site's *custom* badge icon show up in connection with other sites does look weird, so if they address this at all, I would suggest using the *generic* icon (the circles) for these cross-site renderings, rather than going and fetching the badge for each particular site.  That would keep it down to loading two sets of image sprites, current site and generic.  However, showing two different badge icons on a site -- one in the top bar next to your reputation and one in the accounts list -- could *also* be confusing.  I don't think there's a clean solution here that's better than the current behavior.